# Bootcamp Stuck at Downloading Windows Support Software

Tags: bootcamp, windows, high-sierra

Im trying to install Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro - High Sierra.I have downloaded the ISO,Pointed Bootcamp to the file, dragged the partitioning slider and clicked next.It started downloading windows support software.Then I got a message that ,the file was not available.From that moment when I retry to install windows by following the above steps, the progress bar seem to be stuck at the same point and no progress is made.

No partition is created by Bootcamp,i have checked this using Disk Utility.
Do I need a flash drive to install windows?

Comment: What year did you get your MacBook Pro? (Check in 'About this Mac')